# Jquery: Select with option to add new elements

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

Anyone know, if there is a jQuery dropdown plugin with text input field in it, to add new elements to dropdown? I'm looking for something like Facebook did with adding people to groups, if there isn't group You want, You can easily add it.

Something like Jquery chosen but with adding elements instead of filtering.

Comment: Is this going to be confusing for users of your website? Think about other ways you can achieve the same thing. i.e. You could pop up a jquery dialog with a text field in it when the user selects "add new". On saving the new entry it will ajax to the database and add a new option to the end of the drop down select box. This is how google and other sites do it (specifically thinking about labels in Gmail)

Comment: It's really very easy to add new element if You look at what facebook did